# PHP Search and Replace String Randomly

Tags: php

I have the 2 variables/strings below:

```
$article = ('Perfume is a mixture of fragrant word1 and aroma complexes, which can be applied to the human body, animals, word2, objects, and living spaces in order to give off a pleasant word3.');

$words = '{word1|word2|word3|word4|word5}';
```

What I need to do is to search $article for any words in $word and if found randomly replace the word found in $article with a random picked word from $word.

How can I do that please?

Comment: Use array, so randomly pick a value from it.

Comment: $words has to be in the current format

Comment: $words need to be array instead of string

Comment: leave it this way and explode() it to create a dynamic array, this way you won't disturb $words format. You can also use array_rand(explode("|", $words))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to keep everything in the same format;

```
$article = ('Perfume is a mixture of fragrant word1 and aroma complexes, which can be applied to the human body, animals, word2, objects, and living spaces in order to give off a pleasant word3.');
$words = '{word1|word2|word3|word4|word5}';

$words = explode('|', str_replace(array('{', '}'), '', $words));

echo str_replace($words, $words[array_rand($words)], $article);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of $words. Get a random key of the array and str_replace the $article with the randomly chosen words.

```
$words = array('word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4');
$randkeyA = array_rand($words);
$randkeyB = array_rand($words);
echo str_replace($words[$randkeyA], $words[$randkeyB], $article);
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because you're replacing $words[$randkey] with $words[$randkey], so replacing the same word with itself

Comment: Lol, you're right, editted my piece of code. It's still possible this way though the word is replaced by the same word. Your answer is better :)

Comment: Sorted ;)  However, the OP says "$words has to be in the current format"